# Need to iterate through an array to get specific key: value pairs to add to empty object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For this problem, the function accepts an array of strings and returns an object. Keys are supposed to be the number of characters in a string and the value is supposed to be how many time a string with that amount of characters occurred.

I thought I was going somewhere and then I got stuck. I'd appreciate some help on this, I've tried googling it a million different ways but no luck. Thank you!

The result is supposed to look like : characterCount(['apple', 'berry', 'cherry']) // {5:2, 6:1}

```
function characterCount(arr){

  var newObj = {};
  var valueMax = 0;
  var  currentValue = 0;

  for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var key = arr[i].length;
  for(var z=0; z < arr.length; z++){
    if (arr[z].length === arr[i].length){
      currentValue ++;
      if (currentValue > valueMax){
        valueMax = currentValue;
      }
    }
  }
  newObj.key = "valueMax";
}
return newObj;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `Array.prototype.reduce` function. This allows you to take an array, iterate over each value, and return a new, reduced value.

```js
function characterCount(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((counts, str) => ({
    ...counts,
    [str.length]: (counts[str.length] || 0) + 1
  }), {});
}

const counts = characterCount(['apple', 'berry', 'cheery']);
console.log(counts);
```

Alternatively, you could use `Object.assign` instead of spreading the accumulator object.

```js
function characterCount(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((counts, str) => Object.assign(counts, {
    [str.length]: (counts[str.length] || 0) + 1
  }), {});
}

const counts = characterCount(['apple', 'berry', 'cheery']);
console.log(counts);
```

Comment: a bit of an extreme ES6+ for a JS student (based on the task) - but it does look pretty cool.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll have to study this method more!

Comment: @user1514042 - agreed, it might be beyond their current understanding, but it is the optimal solution IMO.

Comment: it's a one liner, but not the optimal one, because you copy the counts array over and over, so it really depends how many different word lengths are in there

Comment: @Icepickle, you're correct. More optimal might have been a better term, when compared with nested for loops. I've added an alternative answer using `Object.assign` which mitigates the copying issue.

Comment: A fat arrow can be used which will make it even 'golfier' and yet highlight the purity of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You could just [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array to accomplish the output

```js
function characterCount( array ) {
  return array.reduce( (agg, cur) => {
    // get the length of the current item
    const len = cur.length;
    // increase the value of the key index with one (if none exist, start with 0)
    agg[len] = (agg[len] || 0) + 1;
    // return the next value for the iteration
    return agg;
  }, {});
}

console.log( characterCount(['apple', 'berry', 'cherry']) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce is arguably better but here is a more straightforward approach.

```js
function characterCount(arr) {
  const countByLength = {};
  
  for (let item of arr) {
    countByLength[item.length] = (countByLength[item.length] || 0) + 1;
  }
  
  return countByLength;
}

console.log(characterCount(['apple', 'berry', 'cherry']));
```